# How do I pass parameters to python FastAPI routers?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

Ideally id like my `server.py` to manage only mounting routers and configuration management.

When I include a router in my main app,

```py
app.include_router(user_data_router)
```

id like to pass instantiation-related parameters to each router.

---

That might look something like this.

```py
app.include_router(user_data_router, params = db_params)
```

Is there a means to do this using FastAPI?

Comment: the custom APIRoute class doesn't seem to cover the parameter passing as the APIRoute class is passed without instantiation.